Merge and synonymize: [personal-pronouns] -> [pronouns]
I propose merging and synonymizing personal-pronouns (5 Qs) into pronouns (19 Qs) (thereby getting rid of the personal-pronouns tag).
To me, this seems about as obvious as it gets.  I'm mostly just posting this for the record.  If no one says "hold on, we should think about this more carefully" in the near future, I'll go ahead and do it.
I think it's a useful synonym to keep around.
The five questions tagged personal-pronouns are:

Is there a gender neutral pronoun in mandarin?
When did "妳" become the second person singular feminine pronoun?
How to learn pronunciation effectively with help of books?
Is there any specifically masculine character for 他
Is it ok to use 他 as a gender neutral personal pronoun (instead of 她) when the subject is known to be female?

The nineteen questions tagged pronouns are:

Why in Chinese Bible (和合本), "you" was translated as "你" instead of "您"?
About 他 and 她 （regarding the song "break up 分手不分离" by z.tao)
Difference between j, q, x sounds and z, c, s sounds?
Is Autumn being referred to by the female pronoun 她? Is this normal?
How to learn pronunciation effectively with help of books?
Is it ok to use 他 as a gender neutral personal pronoun (instead of 她) when the subject is known to be female?
How do I write "One can ..." / "You can ..." (general personal pronoun) in Chinese?
Questions about "本" as Pronoun
How can express a sentence containing relative pronoun in Chinese?
How can I use 其 properly?
Can I say 爸, or do I have to say 爸爸?
Translation of "we", pronoun in official company introduction material
"that" in Mandarin joining clauses or sentences?
How do you use "which" as a relative pronoun?
Differences between 咱们 and 我们？
Is there an old way of pronouncing 牠?
How strict is pronoun gender applied in writing
How gender specific in writing is the character 他
Where is the correct place to use 您 when addressing others?


I merged+synonymized personal-pronouns -> pronouns
I also retagged How to learn pronunciation effectively with help of books? and Difference between j, q, x sounds and z, c, s sounds? which are not about pronouns (but pronunciation).
